# Find all the users within coordinates area

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, geolocation, geospatial

I'm trying to find all users located within a 1 km radius of the provided coordinates, regardless of the direction. However, I'm encountering an issue with the query execution.

I have also tried index: 2d instead of 2dsphere and other mongoose properties such as $near , $nearSphere but none of them provided the results I am looking for.

`Mongoose Query`

```
User.find({
    location: {
      $geoWithin: {
        $centerSphere: [[longitude, latitude], 1 / 6378.1],
      },
    },
  })
    .then((users) => console.log(users))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

`User Schema`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      index: true,
    },
    avatar: {
      type: String,
    },
    location: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Point"],
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

userSchema.index({ location: "2dsphere" });

userSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  const user = this.toObject();
  user.id = user._id.toString();
  delete user._id;
  delete user.__v;
  return user;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```